# Is a prisma.findMany() significantly slower than a prisma.findUnique() query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, next.js, prisma

Is there a significant difference in performance between the following two statements and how do they translate into SQL?

findUnique-Query:

```
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: foo
        }
    })
```

findMany-Query:

```
    const user = await prisma.user.findMany({
        where: {
            id: foo
        }
    })
```

Considering "id" has a UNIQUE constraint.

EDIT:

I was able to log the SQL queries behind the two functions.
They differed only in their endings.

It should be mentioned that I use PostgreSQL.

SQL-ending behind findUnique:

```
WHERE ("public"."User"."id" = $1 AND 1=1) LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3
```

SQL-ending behind findMany:

```
WHERE "public"."User"."id" = $1 OFFSET $2
```

Comment: javascript has functions to measure time spent, why not use it. but i doubt that it will make any difference

Comment: I did and you were right, but my fear is that it will make a difference once the database is populated with more data. Will findUnique return once it found the data and findMany always read through the entire table? or is this a misconception on my part?

Comment: lets say id is primary key, so your query can use the index to pint directly to the right entry, the findunique is only a another notation for SELCT DISTINCT as the query onl can return one entry(primary key), the distinvt makes no difference. An Orm only try to hide sql, and i can't for my life get why anyone will do it, as they can't understand the basics behind the database

Comment: I was able to log a query and it ending with ILIKE $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3 made my confusion even worse. Some PostgreSQL specific stuff...

Comment: ilike is a text comparing function, which uses a case  insensitive, so it will convert it, which would take time. the limit offset and so on will not matter as there is onl yone row to retrieve and all constraints will point to the primary key

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, but you can measure time of compile with this code:

```
const theFunction = async () => {
    // prisma findMany function
}

console.time(theFunction())
await theFunction()
console.timeEnd()
```